# Getting error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Tags: java, android

I'm new to both Java and Android programming. I get the error with this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tView.setText("Blah Blah");     
        }
    });
```

But when I declare reference type "tView" out of the onCreate() method simply the error goes away then the code would be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView tView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tView.setText("Blah Blah");     
        }
    });
```

So what's the difference when I declare reference type "tview" inside the method onCreate() and outside it?

Comment: Local variables vs instance variables. Read up on those terms.

Comment: Basically, this is just Java's rule for when anonymous inner classes refer to variables.  They're allowed to refer to instance members, but they're not allowed to refer to local variables (declared inside a method) that aren't `final`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I searched a little and what I get is that when we use a non-final local variable in an inner class it may cause some unexpected and strange problems when inner class tries to change local variable that doesn't exist after method ends.

Comment: That's what I said with my answer :/

Comment: Why do you thing my answer had "final" in front the text view? You can't use non final variables from outside an inner class. Lol

Comment: Yes you can't! But you didn't say why we can't use non-final variable inside inner class that's why I added this answer and selected it as true and complete answer(your answer is true also).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the scope of the variable. When you define the variable inside the method, the variables scope is only within that method. When you create your `onClickListener`, you are creating an anonymous inner class. This means that you would have to do this, to make the code work:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tView.setText("Blah Blah");     
            }
        });
```

This prevents the `tView` variable from changing.

When you code the other way, the scope changes, and the variable is seen by the entire class, rather than just the method.